# Experimenting JavaScript Properties Attribute defaults

Tags: javascript

While reading a book of JavaScript I read that

> all the attributes of Data Properties defaults to true when **"defined directly on an object"**.

then after some description it again says that

> **"When you are using Object.defineProperty()"**, the values for configurable, enumerable, and
>   writable default to false unless otherwise specified.

I guess, in first statement "defined directly on an object" means using dot operator or by object literal notation like this:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.name = "Mahesh";
```

But is there any way to experiment to check what these attributes have been set to, after the property has been added to the object by either method?

Comment: How about `console.log(obj)`? In Chrome Console or FireBug you should be able to expand that node and see what all its properties are set to.

Comment: There's at least [Object.propertyIsEnumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable). I'm not sure about `configurable` and `writable`.

Comment: @bfavaretto you right, using Object.propertyIsEnumerable() allowed to test my understanding at least for [[enumerable]] and it behaves in the exact way the book says

Comment: @MicahHenning I think we can see only properties of the object in the Chrome console window but not the [property attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548687(v=vs.94).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor):

```
> var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'name');
{"value":"Mahesh","writable":true,"enumerable":true,"configurable":true}
```

`desc` will contain the the flags `configurable` and `enumerable`.  If the property is a data descriptor (no `get` or `set`), `desc` will also contain `value` and the flag `writable`.  If the property is an accessor descriptor, `desc` will also contain the `get` and `set` methods.

Comment: Nice to know. The MDN page on `defineProperty` is missing a link to that.